# Multimedia streaming box with internal storage (built-in or can be added)

Tags: nas, media-player, 1080p, multimedia

I know there are many media players around but I don't know which one would suit my requirements and frankly I rather ask existing users about their experience than reading pages and pages of flashy specs...

### Requirements

My perfect object of desire has these requirement:

1. **Must** have the capability of having or inserting large capacity hard disks (1TB or more).
2. **Must** have an HDMI out connector.
3. **Must** be able to output at 1080 (Full HD) resolution. If that's 1080p even better.
4. **Must** be quiet when turned on and working.
5. **Must** be able to play all kinds of movie content **including** FullHD MKVs.
6. **Must** be software upgradable (either directly from the inetnet or via USB stick or similar) so it will be possible to playback future multimedia formats.
7. **Should** be network connected. **Preferably** WiFi (A/B/G/N standards).
8. **Should** have a nice and intuitive UI.
9. **Should** be available in the EU market (Amazon, eBay etc) that sends to EU members' territory.
10. **Could** have RAID capability of storage disks (so box can as well be used as a robust NAS storage).
11. **Could** have a fast uptime. I prefer a 0 to 5 seconds start-up time to 20+seconds of my current BR Panasonic player.

Did I miss out anything important that a multimedia player should have?

### Additional idea

Do you think that buying a media player like **Boxee Box** + an additional NAS station would be feasible and a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [PopCorn Hour](http://www.popcornhour.com).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a pretty strong idea of what you want.  This is likely not the answer you're looking for, but I'll be "that guy" and suggest building your own box.  It's the absolute best way to have total control over what your system can and can't do.  HTPC cases can make your project look like any other piece of home A/V equipment and you can tailor it to your exact specifications.

[Here's a small selection](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=690&name=HTPC-Media-Center-Cases) to give you some ideas.

Comment: This is the best possible solution for advanced users. Build it to your specifications, set it up to be optimal for your needs and enjoy.